# Why is my audio amplifier oscillating?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, single-supply-op-amp

I'm trying to make a small audio amplifier using a [TDA2822](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tda2822d.pdf) stereo amplifier. It is working as expected, but it has some noise that will make you not hear the audio when I increase the volume on my phone connected to it through the earphone jack.

Why is it oscillating the noise when I increase the audio volume to about 30 percent upwards but I can hear it clearly when the volume is below 30?

Here is my circuit:

[image: op-amp]

I tried adding a pull-down resistor to both input and output and it is still the same. I tried reducing the output capacitor value, but still get the same results.

Advise needed on how to get rid of the high output noise.

Comment: The TDA2822 isn't an op-amp. Do you have a picture of your layout? The datasheet shows 10 uF for decoupling located right on the supply pin of the device.  Do you have a picture of your layout? You may need a resistor from the + input to ground to supply bias currents (again as shown in the datasheet).

Comment: I edited OP's text to correct from op-amp to audio amp.

Comment: Joseph, if we are done here, please take note of this: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have designed isn't what is shown in the [data sheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tda2822d.pdf). They typically show a connection (two channel) like this: -

[image]

- You have used a capacitor on the non-inverting input when it needs a pull-down resistor
- You have used a pull-down resistor on the inverting input when it needs a capacitor.
- The data sheet also shows a Zobel network on the output, yours has none
- You have used a 1 μF supply decoupler whereas the data sheet shows a 10 μF

These are all significant differences but, you could have made other notable "audio-amplifier" errors in how you wired your power source to the IC.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will try it out

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) @JosephAfodu